# Probability of winning a coin toss game

Tags: probability, statistics, recreational-mathematics, closed-form, infinite-product

This may seem like a straightforward probability question but it becomes complicated quickly. I have tried a lot of paths to a solution and would appreciate your help. It is not for school or work.

I flip a coin. If it's heads, I win. But if it's tails, then I need two heads in a row to win. If I then flip another tails, at any time before winning, then I need three heads in a row to win, and so on. The number of heads I need to win is always T+1, where T is the cumulative number of tails flipped during the game. I want to find the overall probability of winning. It is easy to do so numerically. The answer is about 71%. But I want an exact expression, a recursive function to sum the series of probabilities over infinite flips. I imagine it's an infinite recursive product but I've yet to find an answer. Any help would be infinitely appreciated.

Comment: If you have just flipped the $k$th Tails, what is the probability you flip another Tails before flipping $k+1$ consecutive Heads?

Comment: The probability of winning in finite time is about $0.7112119049$

Comment: I doubt there is anything simpler than taking the product (there are functions which represent the product but I do not think they speed up calculation) but it converges fairly quickly: $8$ terms to get over $0.71$ and $26$ terms to get over $0.7112119$

Comment: This was a question from FiveThirtyEight's *The Riddler* in 2018

Comment: This was also posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446754/probability-of-winning-game-whereby-t1-heads-in-a-row-of-a-coin-flip-is-requi

Answer (score 2):

Let $q$ the probability of getting head, $T_k$ be the time that the $k-$th tail appears and $N$ be the number of tails that appears before the win. The probability of winning in a finite time is

\begin{align}
P[N < \infty] &= 1 - \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P[N\ge n]\\
&= 1 -\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\left[\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left\{T_{k} - T_{k-1} < k + 1\right\}\right]\\
&= 1 - \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1-q^{k}\right)\\
&= 1 - \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-q^k\right)
\end{align}